# Extracting Data from listview

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, listview, web-applications, asp.net-4.0

I have a listview "ListView1" and it is linked to my customer table on my customer mssql database. Now, I have added `OnItemDeleting= "ArchiveBeforeDelete"` to the Listview because I want the customer to be archived (moved to my archived customer's database customer table) before it is deleted from the normal database. I have been able to retrieve the selectedindex using `e.ItemIndex` but now I cannot figure out how to then extract the data, more specifically just the CustomerID part, using the index. I've looked through the properties and methods and cannot find one that works.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code in the .aspx page for the listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDeleting= "ArchiveBeforeDelete">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #FAFAD2;color: #284775;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="ArchiveButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Archive" />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerStatusLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerStatus") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerLastNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerLastName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CompanyNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerEmailLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerEmail") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPhoneNumberLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPhoneNumber") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerSubscriptionTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerSubscriptionType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPaymentMethodLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPaymentMethod") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDayLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDay2Label" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #FFCC66;color: #000080;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                    Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel1" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerStatusTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerStatus") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerFirstNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerLastNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerLastName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CompanyNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerEmailTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerEmail") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerTypeTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPhoneNumber") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerSubscriptionTypeTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerSubscriptionType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPaymentMethodTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPaymentMethod") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPickUpDayTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPickUpDay") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPickUpDay2TextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPickUpDay2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" 
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                    Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Clear" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerStatusTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerStatus") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerFirstNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerLastNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerLastName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CompanyNameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerEmailTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerEmail") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerTypeTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPhoneNumber") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerSubscriptionTypeTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerSubscriptionType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPaymentMethodTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPaymentMethod") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPickUpDayTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPickUpDay") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerPickUpDay2TextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("CustomerPickUpDay2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="ArchiveButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Archive" />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerStatusLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerStatus") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerLastNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerLastName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CompanyNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerEmailLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerEmail") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPhoneNumberLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPhoneNumber") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerSubscriptionTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerSubscriptionType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPaymentMethodLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPaymentMethod") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDayLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDay2Label" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                        style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">
                            <th runat="server">
                            </th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Id</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Status</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                First Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Last Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Company Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                E-mail</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Type</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Phone Number</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Subscription Type</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Payment Method</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Pick-Up Day</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                Second Pick-Up Day</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" 
                    style="text-align: center;background-color: #FFCC66;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #FFCC66;font-weight: bold;color: #000080;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerStatusLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerStatus") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerLastNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerLastName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CompanyNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerEmailLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerEmail") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPhoneNumberLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPhoneNumber") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerSubscriptionTypeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerSubscriptionType") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPaymentMethodLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPaymentMethod") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDayLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CustomerPickUpDay2Label" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("CustomerPickUpDay2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tcc_customersConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerId] = @original_CustomerId AND [CustomerStatus] = @original_CustomerStatus AND [CustomerFirstName] = @original_CustomerFirstName AND [CustomerLastName] = @original_CustomerLastName AND [CompanyName] = @original_CompanyName AND [CustomerEmail] = @original_CustomerEmail AND [CustomerType] = @original_CustomerType AND [CustomerPhoneNumber] = @original_CustomerPhoneNumber AND [CustomerSubscriptionType] = @original_CustomerSubscriptionType AND [CustomerPaymentMethod] = @original_CustomerPaymentMethod AND [CustomerPickUpDay] = @original_CustomerPickUpDay AND [CustomerPickUpDay2] = @original_CustomerPickUpDay2" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Customers] ([CustomerStatus], [CustomerFirstName], [CustomerLastName], [CompanyName], [CustomerEmail], [CustomerType], [CustomerPhoneNumber], [CustomerSubscriptionType], [CustomerPaymentMethod], [CustomerPickUpDay], [CustomerPickUpDay2]) VALUES (@CustomerStatus, @CustomerFirstName, @CustomerLastName, @CompanyName, @CustomerEmail, @CustomerType, @CustomerPhoneNumber, @CustomerSubscriptionType, @CustomerPaymentMethod, @CustomerPickUpDay, @CustomerPickUpDay2)" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerId], [CustomerStatus], [CustomerFirstName], [CustomerLastName], [CompanyName], [CustomerEmail], [CustomerType], [CustomerPhoneNumber], [CustomerSubscriptionType], [CustomerPaymentMethod], [CustomerPickUpDay], [CustomerPickUpDay2] FROM [Customers] ORDER BY [CustomerLastName], [CustomerFirstName], [CustomerId]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Customers] SET [CustomerStatus] = @CustomerStatus, [CustomerFirstName] = @CustomerFirstName, [CustomerLastName] = @CustomerLastName, [CompanyName] = @CompanyName, [CustomerEmail] = @CustomerEmail, [CustomerType] = @CustomerType, [CustomerPhoneNumber] = @CustomerPhoneNumber, [CustomerSubscriptionType] = @CustomerSubscriptionType, [CustomerPaymentMethod] = @CustomerPaymentMethod, [CustomerPickUpDay] = @CustomerPickUpDay, [CustomerPickUpDay2] = @CustomerPickUpDay2 WHERE [CustomerId] = @original_CustomerId AND [CustomerStatus] = @original_CustomerStatus AND [CustomerFirstName] = @original_CustomerFirstName AND [CustomerLastName] = @original_CustomerLastName AND [CompanyName] = @original_CompanyName AND [CustomerEmail] = @original_CustomerEmail AND [CustomerType] = @original_CustomerType AND [CustomerPhoneNumber] = @original_CustomerPhoneNumber AND [CustomerSubscriptionType] = @original_CustomerSubscriptionType AND [CustomerPaymentMethod] = @original_CustomerPaymentMethod AND [CustomerPickUpDay] = @original_CustomerPickUpDay AND [CustomerPickUpDay2] = @original_CustomerPickUpDay2">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerFirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerLastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CompanyName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPhoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerSubscriptionType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPaymentMethod" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPickUpDay" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPickUpDay2" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerFirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerLastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPhoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerSubscriptionType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPaymentMethod" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPickUpDay" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPickUpDay2" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerFirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerLastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPhoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerSubscriptionType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPaymentMethod" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPickUpDay" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerPickUpDay2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerStatus" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerFirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerLastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CompanyName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerEmail" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPhoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerSubscriptionType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPaymentMethod" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPickUpDay" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerPickUpDay2" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and then in the codebehind file I have

```
 protected void ArchiveBeforeDelete(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int listIndex = (int)e.ItemIndex;
    }
```

That's all I have, that gets the index. And then I've tried things like @itsme86 has suggested, but all to no avail... All I really want is the CustomerID so that then I can call for that specific ID from the table and then Insert into the other, archived customers table...

Comment: It should be one of the subitems: ListViewItem.SubItems[index].Text

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: @itsme86 I tried that, but .Text does not work, I was looking at another stackoverflow question thing, and it had that, but it was a winform, this is a web app, i probably should have specified, let me see what code I can get you that may be helpful

Comment: @Jake1164: Edited, hope that helps

Comment: So while I was looking at that code from the .aspx page, i saw that the DeleteCommand is defined, so could I perhaps edit it right there and make do two tasks, first copy to other table and THEN it can do delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I suggested in a previous comment, it is possible to edit the DeleteCommand in the .aspx page as follows:

```
INSERT INTO ArchivedCustomers SELECT CustomerStatus, CustomerGroup, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CompanyName, CustomerAddress, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerZipcode, CustomerEmail, CustomerEmail2, CustomerPhoneNumber, CustomerPhoneNumberExt, CustomerType, CustomerSubscriptionType, CustomerCost, CustomerPaymentMethod, CustomerSignUpDate, CustomerPickUpDay, CustomerPickUpDay2, CustomerNotes FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @original_CustomerID; DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @original_CustomerId"
```

As you can see, first it is inserted into the ArchivedCustomers table and THEN it is deleted ocne I'm done with it. One thing to note though, I had to change the property ConflictDetection from CompareAllValues to OverwriteChanges in order to stop getting an error. If someone cares to explain, please do, but for now all I care is that IT WORKS! :)
Big thanks to @Jake1164 , if you hadn't made me post that code, I don't think I would have seen the ability to edit that command as quickly as I did.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the CustomerId on the "tr" tag, so you can get it back out in your event handler. See below...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDeleting= "ArchiveBeforeDelete">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr id="<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>"
        style="background-color: #FAFAD2;color: #284775;">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="ArchiveButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                Text="Archive" />
            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CustomerIdLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CustomerStatusLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("CustomerStatus") %>' />
        </td>
etc.
```

Comment: That might work, not sure, found my own solution that I hinted at in the comments, will post it in a second. Thanks anyways!